# The warning command sends the Embedded message to a different server instead of the Discord server that the command was executed from

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
exports.run = (guild, message, args) => {
    let modRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Staff");
    if(message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)) {
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
        let user = message.mentions.users.first();
        let modlog = guild.channels.find('name', 'mod-log');

        if (!modlog) 
            return message.reply('I cannot find a mod-log channel');

        if (reason.length < 1) 
            return message.reply('You must supply a reason for the warning.');

        if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) 
            return message.reply('You must mention someone to warn them.').catch(console.error);

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x8cff00)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setDescription(`**Action:** Warning\n**Target:** ${user.tag}\n**Moderator:** ${message.author.tag}\n**Reason:** ${reason}`);

        return guild.channels.get(modlog.id).send({embed});
    }
};
```

How can I make this piece of code send the Embedded message to the right Discord server where the command was executed? Something tells me that it's this piece of code here that's doing it "**let modlog = guild.channels.find('name', 'mod-log');**"

Comment: Why don't you just access the guild with `message.guild` ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just get the channel ID, and then send the message specifically in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return message.channel.send({embed});
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.